# Wrong custom-dialog size

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, dialog

I got a problem with a custom dialog in an android application.

I got a Custom Dialog with a ListView inside it. The Dialog itself is 600dp width and the ListView is 600dp as well.

The problem is that the dialog is more than that width value:

[image]
[image: Same image with the "Show layout limits" option enabled]

This is the Dialog layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/promotionListView"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/promotion_dialog_abort"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/annulla"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/promotion_dialog_apply"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/applica"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the layout of the single row: (note that both the width of the layout and the sum of single views is 600dp)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="600dp"    <-- I tried "wrap_content" and "match_parent" with the same result
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/promotionCheck"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/promotionText"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/customerdetail_headertextsize" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/promotionFactor"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/customerdetail_headertextsize" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/promotionPrice"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/customerdetail_headertextsize" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally the Custom Dialog Class

```
public class PromotionDialog extends Dialog {

private boolean authCode;
private Set<OrderDetailDiscount> promotions;
private List<OrderDetailDiscount> selectedPromotions;

private ListView mainListView;

public Response response = Response.CANCEL;

private Button buttonAbort;
private Button buttonAccept;

public PromotionDialog(Context context, boolean authCode, Set<OrderDetailDiscount> promotions) {
    super(context);

    this.authCode = authCode;
    this.promotions = promotions;

    selectedPromotions = new ArrayList<>();

    setTitle("Promozioni");
    setContentView(R.layout.isfa_promotiondialog);

    buttonAbort = (Button) findViewById(R.id.promotion_dialog_abort);
    buttonAccept = (Button) findViewById(R.id.promotion_dialog_apply);
}

}
```

I really can't understand what the problem is, I tried to manually resize the titlebar with no success... what could I possibbly try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `wrap_content` or `match_parent` instead of fixed width/height values in order to support different screen sizes and to simulate table rows you can apply `layout_weight` to each child (column) of a horizontal `LinearLayout`.
Moreover, I suggest you to use `AlertDialog.Builder` APIs.

Here's what I achieved trying to recreate your dialog using my suggestions: 
[image: result]

And here's the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setTitle("Discounts");
        mBuilder.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(), null);
        mBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        mBuilder.create().show();
    }

    class RowItem{
        public String field1;
        public String field2;
        public String field3;
        public RowItem(String f1,String f2, String f3){
            field1=f1;
            field2=f2;
            field3=f3;
        }
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private final ArrayList<RowItem> rows = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

        public MyAdapter(){
            rows.add(new RowItem("Sales","1","5%"));
            rows.add(new RowItem("Extra Sales","2","50%"));
            rows.add(new RowItem("Super Sales","3","70%"));
            rows.add(new RowItem("Completely Free","4","100%"));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount(){
            return rows.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int p){
            return rows.get(p);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int p){
            return p;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent){
           v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            TextView field1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.field1);
            TextView field2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.field2);
            TextView field3 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.field3);
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(position%2==0?"#212121":"#424242"));
            RowItem item = rows.get(position);
            field1.setText(item.field1);
            field2.setText(item.field2);
            field3.setText(item.field3);
           return v;
        }
    }
}
```

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="myText"
        android:id="@+id/field1"
        android:layout_weight="0.6" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="myText"
        android:id="@+id/field2"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="myText"
        android:id="@+id/field3"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" />
</LinearLayout>
```